# Java client peer-to-multipeer using Netty

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I'm writing a process which must connect (and keep alive) to several (hundreds) remote peers and manage messaging / control over them.

I made two versions of this software: first with classic "thread-per-connection" model, the second using standard java NIO and selectors (to reduce thread allocation, but has problems). Then, looking around I found Netty can boost a lot in most cases and I started a third one using it. My goal is to keep resource usage quite low keeping it fast.

Once written the pipeline factory with custom events and dynamic handler switching, I stopped on the most superficial part: its allocation.
All the examples I read use a single client with single connection, so I got the doubt: *I set up a `ChannelFactory` and a `PipelineFactory`, so every `(new ClientBootstrap(factory)).connect(address)` makes a new channel with a new pipeline. Is it possible to make a shared pipeline and defer business logic to a thread-pool?*
If so, how?

Using standard java NIO I managed to use two small small thread pools (threads < remote peers) taking advantage of selectors; I had, however, troubles on recycling listened channels for writing.

Communication should happen through a single channel which can receive timed messages from the remote peer or make a 3-way control (command-ack-ok).

On second hand: once the event as reached the last handler, what happens? Is it there I extract it or can I extract a message from any point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have one bootstrap (i.e one ChannelFactory and one PipeLineFactory). Pipelines, or even individual channel handlers, may be shared, but they are usually created unique per channel.

You can have an ExecutionHandler in your pipeline to transfer execution from the IO worker threads to a thread pool.

But why don't you read the exhaustive documentation at http://netty.io/wiki/ ? You'll find answers to every question of your's there.